# Header not sticking to the top of the screen

Tags: javascript, html, css, sticky

I am working on this website for mobile: [hannelorefischer.com](https://hannelorefischer.com)

However, the header isn't sticking to the top of the screen.
Here's my code:

```html
<div class="show" style="position: -webkit-sticky; position: sticky;  top: 0; display:none; margin-top: 250px; text-align: center; font: Italic 18px/29px 'pensumpro-book'; letter-spacing: 0px; color: #000000; opacity: 1;"><a href="#aktuelles">Aktuelles</a>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; <a href="#buecher">Bücher</a>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; <a href="#texte">Texte</a>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; <a href="#biographie">Biographie</a></div>
```

I might be wrong here, but I believe it stops working when the container div is closed.

Also, I'm summoning the header section with a `.load()` jquery.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you update your snippet please? It doesn't show anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add these properties to your header id

## header

{

```
position: sticky;
top: 10;
text-align: center;
font: Italic 18px/29px 'pensumpro-book';
letter-spacing: 0px;
color: #000000;
opacity: 1;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead
`<div class="show" style="position: fixed;   top: 0; display:none; margin-top: 250px; text-align: center; font: Italic 18px/29px 'pensumpro-book'; letter-spacing: 0px; color: #000000; opacity: 1;"><a href="#aktuelles">Aktuelles</a>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; <a href="#buecher">Bücher</a>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; <a href="#texte">Texte</a>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; <a href="#biographie">Biographie</a></div>`

Answer (score 0):

trying adding this property:

z-index: 2;